# Dejar un elemento fijo con CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

tengo un contenedor de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este contenedor puede tener detalles de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que estos detalles a veces se muestran y a veces no, y lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se muestren la imagen de Play NO se mueva de su posición.

Comentar que estoy trabajando con React y SASS.

Este es el código:

```
<article
        onClick={locked ? void 0 : onClick}
        className={`${styles.thumbnail} ${selected && styles.selected}`}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url("${image}")`,
          filter: locked ? "grayscale(100%)" : "none",
        }}
      >
        <img src={locked ? icons.lock : icons.play}></img>
        {title !== undefined ? (
          <div className={styles.details}>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{mins + ' min'}</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </article>
```

Y este el css:

```
.thumbnail {
    @include thumbnail;
    opacity: 0.5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    > img {
        position: relative;
        left: 75%;
        width: 20%;
        top: -100px;
    }
    .details {
        align-items: center;
        background-color: $primary_regular40;
        height: 37px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
        padding: 3px;
        @include secondary-caption;
        @include horizontal_between;
    }
}
```

Comment: Has probado de ponerle un `position:fixed` y en el contenedor tendras que ponerle un `position:relative` para que no se salga del contenedor.

Comment: Con fixed se queda fijo en la pantalla y cuando hago scroll por la página se ve el botón

Comment: en el contenedor padre ponle un `position: relative` y al elemento un `position: absolute` y posicionanadolo

Comment: Ha vale lo que quieres es que cuando aga scroll se vaia toda la caja para arriba asta el contenido, de dicha caja... entonces solamente te queda hacerle al boton de play. Un `position:absolute` con un `margin-left:90%` para que este a la derecha pero el contenedor tiene que tener `position:relative` para que no se salga de alli.

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias!